# how to get sum of calculated column in SharePoint list view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I would like show sum of calculated column in sharepoint list view as like sum of number column. How to achieve this? thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you not search before asking? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=sum+calculated+column

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this on the list view settings, but you can use a JSLink

Take a look here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30317.sharepoint-2013-displaying-sum-for-calculated-column-in-a-list-view-using-jslink.aspx